# Grouping together class members in python

Tags: python, class

```
class CFT(object):
        self.c3prarea = numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5))
        self.c4prarea = numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5))
        self.c5prarea = numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5))
```

In the class above, I would like to group the 3 members together so that I can iterate over them. What is the best way:

1. Create a list: `ll = [self.c3prarea, self.c4prarea, self.c5prarea]`

or,

2. Create an enum

or,

3. Some other method?

--EDIT based on @9000's soln below, an attempt at using named tuples:

```
self.CFT_names = collections.namedtuple('CFT_names', 'c3prarea c4prarea c5prarea')

self.c3prarea = numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a tuple:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.bars = (numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5)),...)  # however many you need
```

Why a tuple:

- It's immutable, you can't remove or add a member by mistake.
- It's easy to iterate over, or use index access.
- If you need names in the future, you can transparently upgrade to `namedtuple`.

Also, chances are that this 3-tuple may be a simple class by itself, with its own methods that do not depend on other parts of the original `CTF` class. If so, it's worth factoring out; you could use `tuple`directly as a base class.

Comment: thanks @9000, not sure how I can use a namedtuple here?

Comment: You can, but you don't have to. Basically, `namedtuple('bar', ['zeroth', 'first', 'second'])` gives you a class which is a tuple, where `[0]` and `.zeroth` give you access to the same element, `[1]` and `.first` to another element,etc. It allows you to name tuple's elements _when you need it_, and the code that used to use the tuple interface just continues to work. This is a _possible_ upgrade path.

Comment: thanks @9000, does the EDIT in my question to use namedtuples seem ok?

Comment: Well, you need to initialize all three elements in the `CFT_Names` instance: `CFT_Names(numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5)), numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5)), numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5)))`. You can add a custom constructor or a factory method to do this inside `CFT_Names` class.

Comment: there seems to be a problem using namedtuples. I cannot change values in `numpy.zeros(shape=(5, 5))` because it is immutable. Is there a way to get across this using namedtuples or should  I look for some other data structure

Comment: Why, I thought you don't have reassign the values of your `cNparea` items, but modify the numpy-based matrices in them? The _contents_ of tuple items remain mutable: `self.c3parea[1][2] = 12.34` still works.